# How to quickly search for an element in a list

Tags: c++, list

I have two `list<int>`(s) (both sorted)

```
list<int> first;  // length > 24 000 elements
list<int> second; // length > 3 000 000 elements
```

I need to get all elements of the `first` list such that the the element in the `first` list is within 30 of an element in the `second` list.

For example:

```
first = [1,67,1111,10668]
second = [25, 90, 1000, 1004]

output: 
1, 67.
```

I wrote this code in c++ but the code is slow when `second`(s) length is over 10 000.

```
int key = 0;
for (std::list<int>::const_iterator iterator = first.begin(), end = first.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator) 
        {
            key = *iterator;
            for (int j=key;j<key+30;j++)
            {
                std::list<int>::iterator it = std::find(second.begin(), second.end(), j);

                if ( it != second.end() )
                {
                    //print
                }
            }
        }
```

How I can optimize this code to search for elements faster?
Thank you.

Comment: Step 1: Don't use a `std::list`.  You could probably make `second` a `std::set` and use `upper_bound` + `lower_bound`.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to output entries from the first list **only if the corresponding entry** in the second list is within 30? (Nth entry in first list compared to Nth entry in second list.) Or do you want to output entries from the first list if **any entry** in the second is within 30?

Comment: Are we supposed to assume the lists are sorted because both lists in your example are sorted?

Comment: @RichS, I mean it's 
>>Or do you want to output entries from the first list if any entry in the second is within 30?

Comment: @RichS, yes, sorted.

Comment: You're doing over 2,000,000,000,000 iterations if the search fails for all elements. If `second` is sorted you only need to examine a small fraction of its elements. If `first` is also sorted you can narrow it down further. (And the linked list is the most overrated data structure. It's slow and uses a lot of memory.)

Comment: You could use a **binary search** through the second list which would make it considerably faster.  Link: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/

Comment: @AlexG and in the standard library you can use [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) for binary search.

Comment: @AlexG: It can even be done in linear complexity.

Comment: #Jarod42 linear complexity is O (n) where as binary sort is log (n)

Comment: @AlexG: I meant, complete algorithm can be done in `O(n + m)` whereas your suggestion is `O(n * log(m))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in linear complexity a la `std::merge`:

```
void foo(const std::list<int>& first, const std::list<int>& second, const int limit)
{
    auto it1 = first.begin();
    auto it2 = second.begin();

    while (it1 != first.end() && it2 != second.end()) {
        if (*it1 + limit < *it2) {
            ++it1;
        } else if (*it2 + limit < *it1) {
            ++it2;
        } else {
            std::cout << *it1 << std::endl;
            ++it1;
        }
    }
}
```